# Is there a way to handle press action on mentions with react native getstream sdk

Tags: getstream-io, mention, getstream-chat

Hi there problem solvers :)

I am trying to redirect to the user profile that has been mentioned on message bubble, on mention press.

I explored the getstream docs for react native but did not find anything related to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as following:

```
<Channel
  channel={channel}
  onPressMessage={({ message, emitter, additionalInfo }) => {
    if (emitter === 'textMention') {
      // custom implementation navigating to user profile
      // additionalInfo.user corresponds to mentioned user object, which is pressed
      goToUserProfile(additionalInfo.user.id);
    }
  })}
>
  <MessageList />
  <MessageInput />
</Channel>
```

Comment: Hi Vishal thanks for the answer, just tried this and it works,one thing though the message?.user?.id this is the id of the user that sent the message not the one that is mentioned, the mentioned user is within the array under mentioned_user key, if we have multiple mentions in a message it is tricky to navigate to each user mentioned

Comment: Just noticed that if we do it this way it will overwrite the default press handler of the  pressMessage, that has some side effects for example opening links does not work, cant open images etc

Comment: default press handler is available in function params. Just call it in else condition

Comment: I see, thank you :)